# Need to run coroutines after rendering frame

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

My project is for Android. I need to run code after rendering the frame. This is because rendering time could vary vaguely for different frames. I have some time consuming mesh and collider creation routines (So basically there is no room for multithreading because of direct interaction with unity's API). Let's say the profiler shows something like this:

[image]

When I do my coroutines I can't know how much time the rendering takes. So I can't decide how much time budget I have for the coroutine and when to yield it. It could be 20ms or it could be 1ms.

Let's reserve a constant time ,say 10ms, for coroutine execution and assume that target frame rate is 30 and physx time is negligible . Now if rendering take 5ms then 5+10=15ms and I dropped the opportunity to use 15 more milliseconds. On the contrary if the frame had a spike and took 25ms, Then 25+10=35ms and that is greater than the 30FPS target framerate resulting in a visible FPS drop. So either way the constant time has very bad consequence.

But if I could run code after rendering time, I could know exactly how much time I have before the screen refresh and yield at the right moment without losing precious time or the risk of creating a spike with my own hands!!!

I know the codes run according to unity's execution order http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html. I need a workaround or any viable strategy to do coroutines reliably.

Comment: Maybe you can use [this.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html)

Comment: Just a note, Coroutines and multi-threading have nothing to do with each other,

Comment: @BarışÇırıka WOW!! Didn't see that one. Thank you

Comment: @JerrySwitalski You are right. It's just that I am sick and tired of everyone suggesting to use multithreading whenever I say something about coroutines. So I mentioned this to prevent THAT!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    while(true){
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();   
        // My code 
    }
}
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html

As mentioned in the docs, waits for all to be done, right before swapping the buffer. I don't think you can do anything after that without hacking the engine.

Comment: That's exactly what I need.